# Oracle Apiary - securing access to Mock APIs

Tags: oracle, apiary.io, apiary

I am currently using Apiary to design my APIs. I am using the Mock API and accessing the mocks using the private URL’s. We have a large team that uses the mock endpoints. I want to provide additional security to access the url e.g. basic authentication. This is so that even is someone can access the URL, they will still need credentials to get in.

How do I achieve that.

What are my other alternatives to hosting and securing the Apiary APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, there is no way how to get additional security layer to the Apiary Mock Server.

Every user has their own Mock Server per API Project with their personal token in the URL. Any traffic they do is private as far as they won't share the token with anyone.

I'd recommend not to put any sensitive data to the design document as that only complicates stuff for all who collaborate on creating of the API.